# Customize individual parts of the list - List Category Posts plugin

Tags: plugin-list-category-post

I was just wondering if there was anyway to customize individual parts of the lists. So for instance if you go to my site at www.r3entertainment.org and check out the Features page, if you look at the top where it says Gaming's Most Memorable Moments.. is there a way for JUST the title link to be underlined and the author to stay normal in each listed post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do it with only a CSS modification:

```
.lcp_catlist a {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Comment: This works too :)

Answer (score 1):

Since version 0.23 of the [List Category Posts](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/list-category-posts/) plugin, you can set specific html tags and CSS for each element of the list. In you case you would do something like this:

```
title_tag=span title_class=lcp_post title
```

This will look like this in your page:

```
<li>
  <span class="lcp_post_title">
    <a href="http://www.r3entertainment.org/2011/12/12/most-memorable-moment-1/">Most Memorable Moment #1</a>
  </span>
  Super Swayze
</li>
```

Now you should just add `text-decoration:underline` to that class in your CSS.