# List Category Posts plugin - underline links

Tags: templates, plugin-list-category-post

I want to underline links in the default template for the List Category Posts plugin.  I can't find where to do this in the template & styles.  Any assistance would be gratefully accepted.

Comment: Thank you Fernando -- I really appreciate your quick and helpful response.

Comment: You're welcome. If the answer solved the issue, consider marking it as accepted. Regards, and thanks for using the plugin!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this for every link from List Category Posts, you can add this to your theme's css file:

```
.lcp_catlist a {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Check [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/41216/298) for more details on new features that can help you customize even more:

> Since version 0.23 of the List Category Posts plugin, you can set
>   specific html tags and CSS for each element of the list.

If you just want to add this underline, then the best would be to use this new feature instead of a template.